# Can't retrieving the whole collection of users with their relations by using bootstrap model, I only receive single user with his relations

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

Am trying to retreive user details from the database by passing them through model, thus when i click to specific user it show the user specified with some other details required

I only use bootstrap model and i don't know how it works, and i don't know much about javascript with jquery, i only needed this model to accomplish everything

```
/* here is my blade */

@extends('inherit.admin')

@section('info')
@if(count($applieds)>0)
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-hover membertable" style="margin-top: 100px;">

    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th> Forms</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>View Applications</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($applieds as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
        <td> @foreach ($user->post as $key=>$form) 
            @if($key == count($user->post)-1)
            <div class="text-muted" style="float: left;padding-right: 10px">
                <?php echo $form->pivot->status ?>
              </div>
             @endif
              @endforeach
</td>
<td>
     @foreach ($user->post as $key=>$form) 
            @if($key == count($user->post)-1)
             <a href="/downloads/{{$user->id}}"> <button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100px" ><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download form <?php echo $form->pivot->file ?></button></a>

             @endif

              @endforeach
</td>
<td><a href="/approve/{{$user->id}}"> <button class="btn btn-success">Approve</button></a> <a href="/reject/{{$user->id}}"> <button class="btn btn-danger">Reject</button></a></td>
<td>
         <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applications">View applications</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="applications" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          {{-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> --}}
          <h4 class="modal-title">Applications</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-muted" style="float: left;padding-right: 10px">
               @foreach($user->post as $form)
                    {{$form->pivot->company_name}}
               @endforeach
               {{$user->name}}
             </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</td>

    </tr>

    @endforeach
</table>
</div>


@endif
@endsection


/* my controller */

 public function index()
    {
        $applieds=User::where('role_id',4)->with('post')->get();

        return view('Applieds.index',compact('applieds'));
    }
```

No errors, it just show the only two details of the first user and it'll come with only duplication of it when i need to retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below code following: data-target="#applications_{{$user->id}}" and id="applications_{{$user->id}}"

```js
 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applications_{{$user->id}}">View applications</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="applications_{{$user->id}}" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          {{-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> --}}
          <h4 class="modal-title">Applications</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-muted" style="float: left;padding-right: 10px">
               @foreach($user->post as $form)
                    {{$form->pivot->company_name}}
               @endforeach
               {{$user->name}}
             </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: thanks man, it works, even though i still don't know how it works,